# Javascript links stopped working, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that is using js to switch between two different navigation menus. It has always worked up until a week ago or so and I can't figure out why. Wondering if anyone here can point something out to me that I'm not seeing.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="catMenu">
    <a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');">Works</a>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display:block;" >
    ...the 1st menu
</div>

<div class="catMenu2">
    <a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >About</a>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2"  style="display:none;">
    ...the 2nd menu
</div>
```

And Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
       $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
        });
    }
});
```

When I look at my console using firebug, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: showonlyone is not defined
```

but with my lack of knowledge about js, I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Not sure just looking at it, but I think the problem is that you're defining `showonlyone` in a non-global context, so the links don't have access to the function. In fact, I don't think there's any way for elements outside of that `$(document).ready` function to access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to invoke the `showonlyone` function using `href="javascript:showonlyone()"` you'll have to define it in the global scope, currently it's defined inside your `document.ready()` function.

You can also expose it explicitly using the `window` keyword:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.showonlyone = function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
       $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `javascript:` is not needed by the way.

Comment: Thanks haim770 I removed the `document.ready()` function and it's working again. I can accept the answer in 7 minutes ;)

Comment: I don't think removing `document.ready()` is recommended. You *need* the function to run only when the DOM is ready. Just move the `showonlyone` function declaration outside of `document.ready()` or use the `window` solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Building on haim770's answer

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
   $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show();
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide();
      }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
       $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, so move your inline JavaScript out of your HTML and use a `data` attribute to store `thechosenone` variable. Then you can use jQuery to add click methods to your anchors, grab the variable from the data attribute and run the rest of the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="catMenu">
  <a data-chosen="newboxes1">Works</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function () {
    var thechosenone = $(this).data('chosen');
    $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });        
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5kxq06L/6/)

Answer (score 0):

While your format is close to working and haim770 has already shown the problem, I would change your format a bit, here.  Try this:

```
<div class="catMenu">
    <a id="LinkNewBoxes1" class="ToggleDisplay">Works</a>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="NewBoxes1" style="display:block;" >
    ...the 1st menu
</div>

<div class="catMenu2">
    <a id="LinkNewBoxes2" class="ToggleDisplay" >About</a>
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="NewBoxes2"  style="display:none;">
    ...the 2nd menu
</div> 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ToggleDisplay").click(function(e){ //Event Handler for ToggleDisplay clicks
        var BoxToDisplay = $(this).prop("id").replace("Link", ""); //Removes 'Link' from anchor tags ID and assigns to variable
        $(".newBoxes").each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop("id") == BoxToDisplay) //Check if this is the right one to display
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
       e.preventDefault(); //Prevent browser's default action for anchor clicks
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrew!

HTML

```
<div class="catMenu">
    <a href='#' id="LinkNewBoxes1" class="ToggleDisplay">Works</a>
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="NewBoxes1" style="display:block;" >
    ...the 1st menu
</div>
<div class="catMenu2">
    <a href='#' id="LinkNewBoxes2" class="ToggleDisplay" >About</a>
</div>    
<div class="newboxes" id="NewBoxes2"  style="display:none;">
    ...the 2nd menu
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".ToggleDisplay").click(function(e){ 
    var BoxToDisplay = $(this).prop("id").replace("Link", ""); 
    $(".newboxes").each(function(){
        //Check if this is the right one to display
        if ($(this).prop("id") == BoxToDisplay) 
            $(this).show();
        else
            $(this).hide();
    });
   e.preventDefault(); 
   return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s6o6rwon/)